# JavaScript replace every letter in the string with the letter following it in the alphabet error

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to replace every letter in the string with the letter following it in the alphabet.

example:

```
a -> b  
b -> c  
c -> d
```

and so on.

```js
function LetterChanges(str) {
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        if (96 < str.charCodeAt(i) && str.charCodeAt(i) < 123) {
            str = str.replace(str.charAt(i), String.fromCharCode(str.charCodeAt(i) + 1));
        }
    }
    return str;
}
```

so I test is with some string input, I got error on "cod", my code returned "epd" instead of "dpe", can someone please help me with fixing it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Let's see what the code will do with input `cod`:

- Process `c`, next letter in alphabet is `d`, replace `c` for `d`, result is `dod`
- Process `o`, next letter in alphabet is `p`, replace `o` for `p`, result is `dpd`
- Process `d`, next letter in alphabet is `e`, replace `d` for `e`, result is `epd`

You see the error at step 3? `replace` replaces first occurence of the letter the way you use it. One solution would be to create new string by appending the next letters to it. For instance:

```
var newString = '';
for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (96 < str.charCodeAt(i) && str.charCodeAt(i) < 123) {
        newString += String.fromCharCode(str.charCodeAt(i) + 1);
    }
 }
 return newString;
```

---

By the way, your code also has one subtle bug. If your string contains `z` it will be replaced for `{`. You probably want to go back to the beginning of the alphabet and replace it for `a` in that case.

Comment: Why do you use an array as `newString` instead of just a string?

Comment: @QuentinRoy Updated. Probably a better solution to just use String. Maybe also [faster](https://jsperf.com/string-concat-vs-array-join-10000/2). Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Since your `replace` is not restricted to specific positions within the string, it will replace the *first* matching character each time. (It does not replace *all*, because it does not have the `g` modifier set.) So first your leading `c` gets replaced by `d`, the next round replaces the `o` by `p` – and then, in the third round, when your input is already `dpd`, you get `epd` as a result, because the first `d` has been replaced by `e`.

This would be easier, if you did not use `replace`, but simply build a *new* string, that you append the matching “next” character for your current input character to each time, and then at the end you simply return that new string.

Edit:

Also, you current implementation does not handle `z` correctly, since it replaces it with the “next” character `{`, whereas that should rather be an `a`. And `Z` becomes `[`, should be `A` instead. And between `Z` and `a`, there is also a couple of non-letter characters, that you probably don’t want to replace as well.

Here is a function that implements what I suggested above, and also takes `z` and `Z`, and the non-letters into account:

```
function LetterChanges(str) {
    var result = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        // handle "z"
        if (122 == str.charCodeAt(i)) {
            result += "a";
        // handle "Z"
        } else if (90 == str.charCodeAt(i)) {
            result += "A";
        // handle all other letter characters
        } else if ((65 <= str.charCodeAt(i) && str.charCodeAt(i) <= 89) ||
                   (97 <= str.charCodeAt(i) && str.charCodeAt(i) <= 121)) {
            result += String.fromCharCode(str.charCodeAt(i) + 1);
        // append all other characters unchanged
        } else {
            result += str.charAt(i);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(LetterChanges("AaZz+cod!foo")); // output: BbAa+dpe!gpp
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hvyft64p/3/

```
if ((65 <= str.charCodeAt(i) && str.charCodeAt(i) <= 89) ||
    (97 <= str.charCodeAt(i) && str.charCodeAt(i) <= 121))
```

I used 65/89 and 97/121, and `<=` for comparison here, since it just makes a little more sense to me from a logical point of view – these are the actual “boundary” letters we want to take into account here, A/Y and a/y, so using those numbers directly makes the code a little more readable IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good idea to change `str` while you are looping over it.

Here is adapted function that will work.

```
function LetterChanges(str) {
    var strOut='';
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        if (96 < str.charCodeAt(i) && str.charCodeAt(i) < 123) {
            strOut += String.fromCharCode(str.charCodeAt(i) + 1);
        }
    }
    return strOut;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a classic Cezar's Cipher to me (for lower alplha and right shift)

```
function cezarCipher(str,step){
var res="";
step=step%26; //make sure the step is in range
for(var i=0,j=str.length;i<j;i++){
    var nextCode=str.charCodeAt(i)+step;
    if(nextCode>122){
        nextCode=96+(nextCode-123+1);
    }
    res+=String.fromCharCode(nextCode);
}
return res;
}
```

Make the step=1 to get your result.